# ESLint rule to prevent overriding function by creating a const of the same name (especially during assignment)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

Is there an ESLint rule that can catch the following?

```
const foo = () => 1

const bar = () => {
  const foo = foo() // 1. identifier 'foo' is set to undefined in this context 2. invoking foo() results in an error since `foo` is undefined
  return foo
}

> bar()
> Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
    at bar (<anonymous>:4:15)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

In other words, I would like to get a linter error when a const is assigned its own value.

Comment: I think you shouldn't limit this to `const` declarations, *all* `x = x()` assignments are dubious

Comment: The TDZ is named *temporal* because you cannot always know whether variables will be initialised or not (though certainly a few cases could be early errors). Do you want to detect those, or specifically function calls that overwrite the function?

Comment: Good points. I guess I didn't want to be too heavy-handed since `x = x()` doesn't necessarily cause an exception. So I just want to detect things that _will_ cause an exception. And I had thought that the TDZ only happened with `const`s, but according to 2ality it affects `let` as well.

Comment: ESLint's `no-use-before-define` would catch this, though it can be a little aggressive since it will throw on _any_ reference to something before the declaration, even if it's in a callback called after the declaration.

Comment: Thank you, @loganfsmyth! `"no-use-before-define": ["error", { "variables": false }]` provides exactly what I want :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest rule that I know of for your usecase is ESLint's `no-use-before-define`. It will see this as using `foo` before `const foo` and it will error.

The only downside is that this rule doesn't do full code-flow analysis, so it will also error for cases like

```
var getFoo = () => foo;

const foo = 4;

getFoo();
```

because it still sees `foo` as used before `const foo` even though at runtime it is only used after. This may not be an issue if your codebase doesn't do this or can be fixed, but it may be annoying if you're adding the rule to an existing large codebase.